# Sending email using domain alias account in Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I have created an appengine app and the owner is x@foo.com. Foo.com is a google apps account. I've also registered bar.com as a domain alias for foo.com in the google apps admin console.

I'd like my appengine app to send emails from x@bar.com. However, appengine requires that emails be sent from an administrator of the app. But, since x@bar.com isn't a google account (it's just an alias for x@foo.com) I can't add it as an admin my appengine account.

How do I get appengine to send emails from x@bar.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seen this before .. Its a known [issue. Click here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4546) and there really does not seem to be anyway to work around it. Probably not the answer you were wanting to hear. There's a couple of links in that issue tracker with possible workarounds. Hope that helps